# Prevent Chef from running the bash commands twice in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In Chef recipe, I use bash command to set up the env variables.

```
bash 'setup_env' do
code <<-EOH
    echo #{node['foo']} | sudo tee --append /etc/environment
    echo #{node['bar} | sudo tee --append /etc/environment
    for line in $( cat /etc/environment ) ; do export $line ; done
    EOH
end
```

This will write foo and bar into **/etc/environment** every time I run **vagrant provision**

The **/etc/environment** file ends up like this:

```
foo="foo"
bar="bar"
foo="foo"
bar="bar"
```

Is there a method to prevent this bash command from running multiples times in Chef?

Comment: `Chef recipe` WHAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community cookbook [etc_environment](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/etc_environment) can be used to manage the "/etc/environment" file.

Looking at  its code you'll observe it uses a [chef template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) to manage the file:

- [recipes/default.rb](https://github.com/locomote-cookbooks/etc_environment/blob/master/recipes/default.rb)
- [templates/default/environment.erb](https://github.com/locomote-cookbooks/etc_environment/blob/master/templates/default/environment.erb)

Answer (score 0):

While Mark is correct to point out there are alternatives, the more detailed answer is that what you have isn't "idempotent". Chef will run that bit of script every time in runs, and because you have no protections against it, the same values are appended over and over. We offer the `template` and `file` resources to manage file contents in an idempotent manner.